# comparing two cells in certain pattern VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, excel-formula, compare

I'm trying to compare two excel's cells in certain pattern using VBA. The table is separate by empty rows. And the patter is:
I'm looking at column A. If cell A1 is empty I'm moving to next one. If cell A2 is not empty then I'm compering $A2$ to B2, B3, B4, .. etc until I hit the empty cell. If so, then it moves to the next one (not empty), i.e. $A6$ and I'm continue to compering to B6, B7, ...
For defining the scope (range) of the loop I have the following:

```
LastRow1 = This.Sheets("List1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
```

Which loop will fit this kind of pattern? 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A `For ... Next` loop should do the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstood you:
You want to loop through each line in column A till the last row.
Every time you have a value in column A, you want to compare this with the data in column B.

Maybe something like this:

```
LastRow1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Determining the last row in column A
LastRow2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Determining the last row in column B
For i = 2 to LastRow1 'Looping through every row
    If Cells(i, "A") <> "" Then
         For j = i to LastRow2 'looping through each row in column B from the same line as i in column A at that moment, column A6 f.e. will never compare with a value in B2:B5 for example, but only B6 till lastrow in column B
             If Cells(i, "A") = Cells(i, "B") Then
                 <<do something if the value is found>>
             End If
         Next j
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Not the each line in column A. I'm compering only the first value in column A after the empty row with data in column B. In column c we will write the comparison result.
Let's assume that we have empty rows at row 1, 6,15,25. Therefore the patter will look like:
In C2 up to C5 -
`=$A2$=B2 / B3 / B4 / B5`
In C7 up to C15 - 
`=$A7$=B7 / B8 / B9 / B10 etc`